# Why is the first member of this array being overwritten by MPI_Recv?

Tags: c, algorithm, mpi

I'm trying to implement an MPI program to iteratively set each element in an array to the average value of itself and its neighbors (on the previous timestep) while holding the first and last elements cosntant. For one process, this works fine; however, for multiple process, I am not getting the right answer, and in particular, the first array element is always overwritten.

My initialization step seems to be working correctly, at least as far as the "before computation" output is concerned, which prints the same vector regardless of whether the number of processes used is 1 or more.

One thing I'm not entirely sure of is whether I'm using MPI_Request and MPI_Status correctly; the variables to pay attention to are `sendL`, `sendR`, and `status`.

I tried to only include the relevant portions of code; "..." marks where something is missing. Some of these ellipses have comments to explain what was removed. Both the parallel and single-process implementations are given for comparison.

```
...
#include "mpi.h"

... //definition of f() for initialization

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  int         id, p, i, j, k, n, t, m, v, vp,
              lbound, ubound, block_size, offset;
  double      startwtime, endwtime;
  float       time;
  MPI_Request *sendL, *sendR;
  MPI_Status  *status;  /* return status for receive */
  double      *prev, *cur, *temp;

  ... // initialize MPI; get PE rank and size

  .... // set the following:
       // n = vector length, m = num iterations, k = buffer size
       // v = verbose (true/false)

  // Memory allocation for output from MPI functions
  // Note that I never actually initialized these. Is this a problem?
  sendL = (MPI_Request *) malloc(sizeof(MPI_Request));
  sendR = (MPI_Request *) malloc(sizeof(MPI_Request));
  status = (MPI_Status *) malloc(sizeof(MPI_Status));
  // Memory allocation for data array.
  block_size = (n/p+2*k);
  prev  = (double *) malloc( sizeof(double) * block_size);
  cur   = (double *) malloc( sizeof(double) * block_size);

  ... //malloc error handling

  t = 0;
  /* The following block is for a single process. It works correctly. */
  if(p==1){
     // Initialization
     startwtime = MPI_Wtime();
     for(i=0;i<n;i++)  prev[i] = f(i,n);
     cur[0] = f(0,n); cur[n-1] = f(n-1,n);
     if(v){
       printf("Before calculation\n");
       for(i=0;i<n;i++) printf("%f ",prev[i]);
       printf("\n");
     }
     while (t < m) {
      for ( i=1 ; i < n-1 ; i++ ) {
            cur[i] = (prev[i-1]+prev[i]+prev[i+1])/3;
       }
      temp = prev; prev = cur;  cur  = temp; t++;
      }
     if(v){
       printf("After calculation:\n");
       for(i=0;i<n;i++) printf("%f ",prev[i]);
       printf("\n");
     }
     endwtime = MPI_Wtime();
     time = endwtime-startwtime;
     printf("Sequential process complete, time: %f\n", time);
     return MPI_Finalize();     
  }
  /* Here is my parallel implementation. It has problems. */
  else{
     if (id == 0){
         startwtime = MPI_Wtime();
     }
     // Initialization
     offset = id*(n/p)-k;
     for(i=0;i<block_size;i++)  prev[i] = f(i+offset,n);
     cur[0] = f(0,n); cur[block_size-1] = prev[block_size-1];
     if (id == 0){
         for (i=0;i<k;i++){
            prev[i] = f(0,n);
            cur[i] = prev[i];
         }
     }
     if (id == p-1){
         for (i=block_size-k;i<block_size;i++){
             prev[i] = f(n-1,n);
             cur[i] = prev[i];
         }
     }
     if(v && id == 0){
       printf("Before calculation:\n");
       for(j=k;j<(n/p)+k;j++) printf("%f ",prev[j]);
       for(i=1;i<p;i++){
         MPI_Recv(prev+k,(n/p),MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION,i,2,MPI_COMM_WORLD,status);
         for(j=k;j<(n/p)+k;j++) printf("%f ",prev[j]);
       }
       printf("\n");
     }
     else if (v){
       MPI_Isend(prev+k,(n/p),MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION,0,2,MPI_COMM_WORLD,sendL);
     }
     lbound = (id == 0) ? (k+1) : (1);
     ubound = (id == p-1) ? (block_size-k-2) : (block_size-2);
     while (t < m) {
        for ( i=lbound ; i < ubound ; i++ ) {
              cur[i] = (prev[i-1]+prev[i]+prev[i+1])/3;
         }
        temp = prev; prev = cur;  cur  = temp; t++;
        if (t%k == 0){
          if (id > 0){
           // send to left
           MPI_Isend(prev+k,k,MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION,id-1,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD,sendL);
          }
          if (id < p-1) {
           // send to right
           MPI_Isend(prev+block_size-2*k,k,
                   MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION,id+1,1,MPI_COMM_WORLD,sendR);
          }
          if (id < p-1){
           // receive from right
           MPI_Recv(prev+block_size-k,k,
                   MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION,id+1,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD,status);
          }
          if (id > 0) {
           // receive from left
           MPI_Recv(prev,k,MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION,id-1,1,MPI_COMM_WORLD,status);
          }
        }
      }
     if(v && id == 0){
       printf("After calculation\n");
       for(j=k;j<(n/p)+k;j++) printf("%f ",prev[j]);
       for(i=1;i<p;i++){
         MPI_Recv(prev+k,(n/p),MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION,i,2,MPI_COMM_WORLD,status);
         for(j=k;j<(n/p)+k;j++) printf("%f ",prev[j]);
       }
       printf("\n");
     }
     else if (v){
       MPI_Isend(prev+k,(n/p),MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION,0,2,MPI_COMM_WORLD,sendL);
     }
     if (id == 0){
        endwtime = MPI_Wtime();
        time = endwtime-startwtime;
        printf("Process 0 complete, time: %f\n", time);
     }
     return MPI_Finalize();     
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "before computation" output overwrites the `prev` pointer. Oops.

Answer (score 2):

First things first. This part of the code is overly complicated:

```
MPI_Request *sendL, *sendR;
MPI_Status  *status;  /* return status for receive */

sendL = (MPI_Request *) malloc(sizeof(MPI_Request));
sendR = (MPI_Request *) malloc(sizeof(MPI_Request));
status = (MPI_Status *) malloc(sizeof(MPI_Status));
```

Handles in MPI are simple types like integers or pointers. Dynamic allocation makes no sense in this case. Status is also a simple structure with 3-4 fields and it makes no sense to allocate it on the heap. Use stack variables instead:

```
MPI_Request sendL, sendR;
MPI_Status status;
```

There is also another problem: you initiate non-blocking sends but never guarantee their completion, i.e. you never call `MPI_Wait` or `MPI_Test` on the request handles. They might never actually get progressed to completion, which can lead to deadlock in the receive code. Actually you do not need these non-blocking calls at all but rather use `MPI_Sendrecv`, which was designed specifically for the purpose that you use the combination of `MPI_Isend`/`MPI_Recv`. The following code:

```
if (id > 0){
   // send to left
   MPI_Isend(prev+k,k,MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION,id-1,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD,sendL);
}
if (id < p-1) {
   // send to right
   MPI_Isend(prev+block_size-2*k,k,
             MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION,id+1,1,MPI_COMM_WORLD,sendR);
}
if (id < p-1){
   // receive from right
   MPI_Recv(prev+block_size-k,k,
            MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION,id+1,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD,status);
}
if (id > 0) {
   // receive from left
   MPI_Recv(prev,k,MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION,id-1,1,MPI_COMM_WORLD,status);
}
```

can be replaced by:

```
int prev_rank, next_rank;

prev_rank = (id > 0) ? id-1 : MPI_PROC_NULL;
next_rank = (id < p-1) ? id+1 : MPI_PROC_NULL;

...

MPI_Sendrecv(prev+k, k, MPI_DOUBLE, prev_rank, 0,
             prev+block_size-k, k, MPI_DOUBLE, next_rank, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
MPI_Sendrecv(prev+block_size-2*k, k, MPI_DOUBLE, next_rank, 1,
             prev, k, MPI_DOUBLE, prev_rank, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
```

The rank checks are removed using the concept of a null process, that is a process with rank `MPI_PROC_NULL`. It is a very special rank in MPI - you can always send to and receive messages form it and those operations are simply no-ops. Note that the correct MPI data type is `MPI_DOUBLE`. `MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION` is for the Fortran data type `DOUBLE PRECISION`. Because `MPI_Sendrecv` is a blocking call, each invocation is written so as to send data to the next process while receiving data from the previous one in order to prevent deadlocks.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help, especially for the MPI_Sendrecv() function, which I didn't know about. As I said in my answer, the fundamental problem was the overwriting of the initial values in the code to print out the initial array, but it can't hurt to clean up the code somewhat as well.

Comment: Also, are you sure that this can cause a deadlock? It's true that I never explicitly wait on any of the Isend() calls, but since the Recv() calls **are** blocking, it seems to me that there's no way for a cycle to occur; and since rank 0 eventually waits on all other ranks, all process finish before output.

Comment: In this case - no, because of the null ranks on both sides (communication with them always succeeds immediately, even given blocking calls). But with periodic boundary conditions it could. Besides written so it takes 2 "time steps" to complete the swaps. If you swap the receive parts in both send-receives, it will take `2*p` "time steps". (Also this wasn't even meant to be an answer to your question as you have already solved the overwriting issue.)

Comment: @KyleStrand, testing or waiting on non-blocking requests is required by the MPI standard in order to guarantee proper operation completion. Failure to do so makes your program non-portable - it might work with some MPI implementations but not with others. It could also lead to memory leaks as internal request structures might not get released after completion. In your case it works, because `MPI_Recv` calls progress pending sends internally, but this is quite specific case.